# How to get a value from returned JSON in HTML?

Tags: html, json, post, promise, fetch-api

My client side looks like this:

```
filename="random_filename.docx"
var response = await fetch("https://backend.wl.r.appspot.com/scriptstuff", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors', 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ file: filename })
  }); 

  var data = response.json();

  console.log(data);
```

and my backend return looks like this

```
response = jsonify({'prediction': str(prob)})
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
return response, 200
```

I receive a promise with the value of 'prediction', but I'm not sure how to access that or why the current code isn't working.

EDIT: adding await before response.json() works

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function upon a promise being fulfilled by appending a `.then()` to the fetch request. If you're already receiving the JSON object then the values can be accessed by `data.some_key`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but first store str(prob) into a variable and then create an object with it. I think jsonify() takes things very literally.